# Create function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a jquery function, and used below code, but not getting any output. Please tell me the process to make it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $.fn.myplugin = function(){
            alert(this.id);
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $("#sample").myplugin();
</script>
```

Comment: do you have the element with an id "sample" somewhere in your document? is this `script` tag placed below the HTML? if not, wrap the code with `$(document).ready(function() { // here goes your code });`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see the working code here – http://jsfiddle.net/gryzzly/YxnEQ/

Note that you need an element with id "sample" to be present in your document when you are running the above code. Also, the `this` is pointing at jQuery object, so in order to get the elements id, you need to use either of the following:

```
alert( this[0].id );
```

or

```
alert( this.attr('id') );
```

The first is preferable, because it's faster.

Comment: what browser you are in? is jQuery loaded on the page?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  myplugin($("#sample"));
 });

  function myplugin(obj){
  alert(obj.id);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Actually i was not able to workout solution given by @Kanishka , so this answer is an improvement to his solution .Just thought of sharing it

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sample").myplugin(this.id);
});

function myplugin(id) {
    alert(id);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
        alert(this.id);
```

to

```
        alert(this[0].id);
```

As you're getting a jQuery object array.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(this.attr('id'));
```

`this` in that context is a jQuery object, not a raw DOM element.

Comment: so what should be the code & how I will implement any jquery function?